# Can I replace が with の in this sentence(私に···あなたが命を懸けて護る価値はない.)

Tags: nuances, particle-の, particle-が

私に···あなたが命を懸けて護る価値はない.

From what I heard, 命を懸けて is a set phrase which means the action of risking one life(which means the whole phrase is considered as a verb right?)

Out of curiosity, can I change the が at あなたが to の. The reason is because あなたの命 would refer to "Your life" and following あなたの命 with を懸けて would mean risking your life which is the exact same meaning as あなたが命を懸けて right?

So I just I want to know if I'm allowed to do this and is there any nuance changing が here to の in this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Generally yes. あなたが命を懸けて and あなたの命を懸けて will mean something similar in a typical context.

However, with the あなたの命を懸けて option, you make the subject implicit (because the sentence will lack a noun marked with -が), making more room for interpretation. The implicit subject could be あなた and that's probably the most reasonable estimation, but it could be someone else. In a scenario "your life" (あなたの命) is under a third person's control, that person will also be a reasonable candidate to fill the implicit subject slot.